# Using context to access Prestashop config values

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to use `$this->context->shop` to access, on my case, prestashop store name.

Is it possible or will you recommend using `Configuration::` class?

Comment: Of course, you can access it with `$this->context->shop->name`.

Comment: Thanks you @TheDrot, will try and comment if works for your answer ;)

Comment: Ok, working perfectly @TheDrot! You can post your answer and I'll commend it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an not multisite environment it is recommendable

```
   Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.